# Accessing value of pointer stored in vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, struct

I'm trying to create a triangle mesh grid to write code for Finite Element Analysis. I know there's software already written to do it, but this is for a class project.

What I'm trying to do is take the region and divide it up into evenly spaced nodes (mesh points). Each node has 6 triangles connected to it which need to be used in the calculation. To make things easier, I created two structs, one for nodes and one for the triangles.

Below, I have a minimum working example of what I'm trying to implement in my code. However, this code receives a segmentation fault on the line where it is assigning the x,y values to the vertex. The error produced in gdb states:

```
With using vectors (as per the minimum working example)
----------------------------
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400f90 in std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*> >::operator[] (this=0x0, __n=0)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:771
771           { return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); }

// Running backtrace
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400f90 in std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*> >::operator[] (this=0x0, __n=0)
    at /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_vector.h:771
#1  0x0000000000400a87 in main () at minimumexample.cpp:28
----------------------------
```

And I'm not sure how to figure this out. A similar error is produced if instead of vectors I use arrays, so I don't think it is a problem with just the vector class?

```
With arrays instead of vectors
----------------------------
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400929 in main () at minimumexample.cpp:28
28        MyGrid[0].Triangles[0]->vertex[0]->x = 0;

// Running backtrace
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400929 in main () at minimumexample.cpp:28
----------------------------
```

Below is a minimum working example of what I'm trying to do. I'm not sure why I'm getting an out of bounds error because I don't see where I'm going out of bounds in the vectors at all.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Triangle;

struct Node
{
  double x; 
  double y;
  vector<Triangle*> Triangles;  
  Node() : Triangles(6) {}
};

struct Triangle
{
  vector<Node*> vertex;
  Triangle() : vertex(3) {} // 3 vertices per triangle
};

int main()
{
  int size = 10;
  vector<Node> MyGrid(size);
  double spacing = .25;

  // The below code should create 3 vertices of the triangle with the
  // three vertices of the triangle (x,y) defined as locations (0,0) for the 
  // first vertex, (1,0) for the second vertex, and (1,1) for the third.

  MyGrid[0].Triangles[0]->vertex[0]->x = 0; // Line 28: Error here
  MyGrid[0].Triangles[0]->vertex[0]->y = 0;
  MyGrid[0].Triangles[0]->vertex[1]->x = 1;
  MyGrid[0].Triangles[0]->vertex[1]->y = 0;
  MyGrid[0].Triangles[0]->vertex[2]->x = 1;
  MyGrid[0].Triangles[0]->vertex[2]->y = 1;

  return 0;
}
```

For anyone else who runs into this problem, this is the working version of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Triangle;

struct Node
{
  double x; 
  double y;
  Triangle *Triangles;  
};

struct Triangle
{
  Node *vertex;
};

int main()
{
  int size = 10;
  vector<Node> MyGrid(size);
  double spacing = .25;

  // Allocate 6 Triangle objects into the variable Triangles
  MyGrid[0].Triangles = new Triangle[6];
  // Allocate 3 nodes for Triangles[0]'s vertex
  MyGrid[0].Triangles[0].vertex = new Node[3];

  MyGrid[0].Triangles[0].vertex[0].x = 0; 
  MyGrid[0].Triangles[0].vertex[0].y = 0;
  MyGrid[0].Triangles[0].vertex[1].x = 1;
  MyGrid[0].Triangles[0].vertex[1].y = 0;
  MyGrid[0].Triangles[0].vertex[2].x = 1;
  MyGrid[0].Triangles[0].vertex[2].y = 1;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Segfaults are usually caused from attempting to dereference a pointer in the heap which has no connection to a previous allocation call.

Comment: The edited version fixes the segfaults but I doubt it will be any use. Remember the other question/answer that gave you the idea to use pointers in the first place rather than `vector<Triangle>`? Did you solve the problem of that question, or did you just create the same problem all over again?

Answer (score 1):

In `Node::Node`,

```
  vector<Triangle*> Triangles;  
  Node() : Triangles(6) {}
```

you are simply initializing `Triangles` to be a `vector` of size `6`. This does not give you valid memory locations to work with - the `Triangle*`'s in `Triangles` need to be allocated using `new`.

Usually, you don't need a `vector<Triangle*>`. Simply use a `vector<Triangle>` instead.

Comment: Thank you fro your help! The fixed version of the code has been edited into the original post.

Answer (score 0):

The second version of the program avoids the segfault but does not solve the
problem that the use of pointers was supposed to solve in the first place.

First of all, though this is incidental to your problem,
I highly recommend writing `Triangle* triangles`
(note lower case `t`) rather than `Triangle* Triangles`, so that
`triangles` is clearly a variable name and not a class name.

The problem you have now is that if you continue to initialize the
other elements of `MyGrid` in this way, each of the
three `Node` objects that should be at the vertices 
of one of your mesh triangles will create
its own `Triangle` object to cover that triangle. You would end up with
three `Triangle` objects where you want just one, and there would be no
`Triangle` that had all three of the correct `Node` objects linking to it.
Moreover, none of the `Node` objects that in any of the `Node* vertex`
arrays of any `Triangle` is in the original `vector<Node> MyGrid`,
and none of them has links to any `Triangle` (even the `Triangle` that links
to it), let alone the six `Triangle*` pointers it should have.

What you have is not even the beginnings of a mesh,
it's doomed to be a collection of "islands", one for each
member of `MyGrid`, each one completely isolated from all the others.

Notice that when you write `MyGrid[0].Triangles[0].vertex[0].x = 0`,
if all the objects were properly connected to each other then
`MyGrid[0].Triangles[0].vertex[0]` is simply a pointer to another `Node`,
presumably a member of `MyGrid` (why would you store `Node` objects
anywhere else?), so a more direct way to do the same thing would
be to determine which member of `MyGrid` this is, for example member `1`,
and write `MyGrid[1].x = 0` instead.

Actually, something like `MyGrid[1].setCoordinates(0,0)` to set both the
x and y coordinates simultaneously would make your program easier to read
and less likely to have mistakes.

A better strategy might be to change the definitions of `Node` and `Triangle`
back the way they were before, 
but this time, after you you create your vector of `Node` objects,
for each `Node` call a member function that initializes its coordinates
(or initialize the coordinates in a constructor of a `Node` that you then
`push_back` onto the `vector<Node>`);
then start creating `Triangle` objects. For each `Triangle` you create,
for each `Node` that the `Triangle` is supposed to connect to,
you need to insert the `Triangle` in the `triangle` list of that `Node`
and you need to insert the `Node` into the `vertex` list of that `Triangle`.
Since you always do these assignments in pairs, it pays to have a single
function call that does both. To make things even more convenient and
less error-prone, have *that* function called three times by a member function
of `Triangle` that takes three `Node*` parameters, one for each `Node`
the `Triangle` is to connect to.

If this isn't clear enough, try drawing a diagram of a few of the `Triangle`
objects and the `Node` objects, with pointer arrows connecting them
the way they are supposed to be connected. Whatever you write has to
create a data structure with all those pointers properly linked.

Comment: Thanks. This is actually the solution that I was looking for because I would like to use pointers because the idea I'm going for is to link them to those already defined.

[This](http://i.imgur.com/fkPFDqn.png) is how the meshgrid is to be defined (ignore the black box), with each node not at the bounds having [these triangles](http://i.imgur.com/w1wQ5lB.png). So what you're saying is to make each Node have an x,y value, then each vertex points to the appropriate Node that stores those x,y values?

Comment: Yes, I think that is how you want to get started. It also seems that each time you give one object a pointer to a second object, you want to give the second object a pointer back to the first object. At least that's what the design with the vectors of pointers in both classes seemed to be well suited to do.